# Use local int to refer to constant defined as a macro

Tags: c

I am self-taught C novice, and I am struggling to accomplish the following:

In my main() loop, I am incrementing an int "i". I have a separate header file where I have defined several macros that I would like to call in my main with "i".

For example, in my separate header file, I have the following constant:

```
#define _1 0x06
```

If I wanted to call `_1` using `i` when `i = 1`, how do I convert `i` to `_1` so that I can use it later; in this case, I want to assign the value of `_1`, which is `0x06` in my header file, to a specific index in a  byte array, such as:

```
Array[3] = _1
```

Every time my loop iterates, I would like to have a different value assigned to the array index, such as:

```
Array[3] = _i
```

I hope that my question makes sense. Please pardon my lack of familiarity with technical programming verbiage.

Comment: `_1` is not a very good identifier, and what is the relation between the macro value and `i`?

Comment: Not trying to be smart ass but? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_longjmp.htm
Which c compiler gcc? Do you have a godbolt example?

Comment: Make a table of those macros: `int table[] = { _0, _1, _2, ...};` Then you can use `i` as the index into that table, e.g. `Array[3] = table[i];`

Comment: Please provide more context. Do you also intend to use things like _2, _3, _4, _5.... because then I am with David Raniert . More context would also help finding the https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem in this and coming up with a solution to what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be done with the preprocessor, the value of the iterator is unknown at compile time, but you can use a lookup table:

`int lookup[] = {0x00, 0x06, 0xab, ...};`

Then, loop using the iterator as offset:

`for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) x = lookup[i];`

Comment: This works. I also tried the macro table as suggested by user3386109 and that worked as well, with no observable difference in speed. Thank you! For anyone who was wondering, I am writing a program in MPLAB IDE for a PIC16F microcontroller using microchip's free XC8 compiler. I am new to the PIC game as well so the learning curve is very steep. Baby steps!

Comment: @kevinaguy If this is for a PIC then you must use `uint8_t` instead of `int` and also do `const uint8_t lookup[]` to make the lookup table end up in flash where it should be. Generally, I would strongly suggest to stay clear of 8 bit microcontrollers if you are new to C. They are much harder to program than 32 bitters, since 8 bitters require a whole lot more detailed C knowledge.